# Gradle - create Jar from Spring Boot project which consist only of .class files

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have problem with Gradle. I have a simple spring boot project and I want to jar it with only the package and .class files inside. What I'm receiving now is 3 folders BOOT-INF, META-INF and org.springframework.boot.loader.

Comment: Is it supposed to be a runnable jar? Or a library?

Comment: @Strelok library.

Comment: Then actually remove the `org.springframework.boot` gradle plugin from your project.

Comment: Like apply plugin : 'org.springframework.boot' and the classpath from dependencies section ?

Comment: See my answer on how to use spring boot but not use its plugin that is only meant for building actual applications vs libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the gradle plugin. It is only useful if you want to build a spring boot app.

Here is how to build a library (but still use spring boot):

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    dependencyManagementPluginVersion = '1.0.1.RELEASE'
  }

  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:$dependencyManagementPluginVersion"
  }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:$springBootVersion"
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web' // no need to specify version
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're creating a .jar artifact of a Spring-boot project and want to use it as an external dependency in another app (eg. referring to a `main` class within), you can add this to your Boot app's `build.gradle` file in addition to the .jar publishing config:

```
bootRepackage  {
    classifier = 'exec'
}
```

(Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/6565ff616a827c22b4235d8ce2fb9a94eb4ad4c8?short_path=1c5002a#diff-1c5002aface9c68d53c46740b5f095e5)